# How can I execute one command from cmd while executing a script in WSL?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a build script I'm using in a project I'm currently working on. I found that a certain command only works from cmd and not WSL, but I want to continue to work in WSL.

I have something like this:

```sh
command1 && command2 && command3
```

Say `command2` only works in cmd. How can I make this script switch to cmd, execute a command and switch back to WSL?

Comment: @tripleee I tried a few things and `cmd.exe /c "command2"` indeed works. Thanks! Just curious, what does `/c` do? Google can't search for puncuation unfortunately.

Comment: Searching for "cmd options" gets me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd (which of course is a Microsoft page, so it will probably have moved by the time you try to click).

Comment: Use the command `cmd /?` or `"%ComSpec%" /?` and read all about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `cmd /c "command2"`.

The option `/c` says to read the script from the next command-line argument, rather than from a file or the interactive prompt.

Comment: I tried to look for a duplicate but couldn't find one.

Comment: Probably because such a duplicate doesn't exist.

Comment: You should generally use the `/D` option with `cmd.exe` too, and may also want to consider `/mnt/c/windows/system32/cmd.exe`.